# Extract digits and hyphen from a line in file

Tags: regex, perl

I have to extract string with particular format from a file. i.e string format is 1 followed by hyphen and 7 digits.

```
for ex.

    #CARES# AR_NUMBER=1-4742637
```

here I have to extract only 1-4742637.
Help me, how to extract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will capture that: `/\b(1-\d{7})\b/`

As demonstrated:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = <<'END_TEXT';
for ex.

    #CARES# AR_NUMBER=1-4742637
END_TEXT

if ($text =~ /\b(1-\d{7})\b/) {
    print "$1";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1-4742637
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($subject =~ m/(1-[\d]+)/) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}


(1-[\d]+)

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(1-[\d]+)»
   Match the characters “1-” literally «1-»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «[\d]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Comment: I do not understand why you're using a character class. Also your expression fails if you use `\A` and `\Z` for the input provided by the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as:

`([0-9-]+)`

or specifically for your case:

`(1-\d{7})`

and the first captured group `\1` or `$1` will contain what you want.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/pY4gB6

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$var =~ /1-\d{7}/
```

{} for number of matches

Answer (score 0):

```
1-\d{7}
```

will select the required part.